# Reduce time taken to query from larger tables in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I am developing  C# desktop app which queries from a large table in a SQL Server 2008 R2 database.

In some of my queries, it is needed to use * , because all the information are required to fetch.

And the table I mentioned is getting bigger day by day as it is in a production environment. Is there any way to speed up the process. Currently one query takes about 2 minutes. So I have set `SqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 0;`

Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks !

Comment: Could you show part/all of the code you use to query, since that is relevant. (Hide/Change sensitive info)

Comment: Some general tips would be to introduce indexes, remove subqueries (see if you can use joins instead)

Comment: if you want to reduce the time it takes to return records, look at what you are returning in regards to the `Select *` perhaps you could filter it down to return `Top 100 rows` or you could add some `Where Clause criteria` if you are not sure.. get with your DBA and run an Execution Plan and look into using `Indexes`

Comment: Avoiding `SELECT *` isn't (completely) about speed - it's usually more about preventing a downstream query/interface being broken.

Comment: Consider using one of the SQL command line queries which is used to archive very large databases and runs much quicker than c# queries.   I usually run from c# as a batch file (run using Process class) and create csv which can be read from c#.  I usually use Sqlcmd.exe.  See msdn : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/command-prompt-utility-reference-database-engine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you create indexes in the tables? or Db proparliy normalised? if so in c# you can use Cache to store data when you getit. Also howmnay records are we talking about? if more than 100K its best to Datadictionary to load customly. may be theese tips will help to spped up